# 何もかも and 全部 usages

Tags: word-choice

What's the difference in using 何もかも and 全部?
Eg:

何もかも捨てる

全部捨てる

I have also seen:

何もかも全部捨てる

What are the differences and when should I use them

Answer (score 1, accepted):

全部 just objectively says that the statement applies to "all" the things concerned.

何もかも is more emphatic, in that it suggests the statement applies to all the things concerned, whatever or whichever it may be. It's kind of like "whatsoever" in English, except it can be used by itself.

Using both, as in 何もかも全部捨てる, is like in English saying "any...whatsoever"

Comment: I take that as 何もかも really just means 全部 but a more theatrical, emphasized version of 全部. And 何もかも全部 is above even 何もかも in terms of emphasis?

Comment: @Newbie That's correct